# CocoaPods issues while adding a new pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift4, ios-charts

My CocoaPods works fine until I try to install a new one.
If I try to install a new pod, then there are several issues in charts pod, else it works fine.
How do I fix it?

The errors show up as below:

[image: Issues in charts]

My podfile is as below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Tranquil' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

# Pods for TranquillocationText
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'UICircularProgressRing'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0' . //if i try to add this pod then error occurs
pod 'Charts'
end
```

Comment: `NSAttributedStringKey` that smells Swift 4. While you seem to be using Swift 3 only. So as you did for Alamofire adding `'~> 4.0'`, add the version that is Swift 3 compliant. According to this: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/releases should be the version tagged  `3.0.3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Ensure swift language version of your project. Here is how you can see/check your swift language version.

[image]

You have two options as solution to your query:

1. *If your project has Swift versio 4.0* 
   - You should choose/download POD compatible to your project's swift language (Share me POD info and swift version, so I can provide you exact pod version version for your pod library suitable for project).
2. *If your project has swift version below 4.0* 
   - You need to migrate your project into Swift 4.0 (if you've not migrated it). Here is ref question and answer, how to migrate from swift (below) <4.0 to 4.0.

   - [Xcode 9 Swift Language Version (SWIFT_VERSION)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46338588/5638630)

According to snapshot added by you in your question - Swift 3.x is your current project language version and [pod 'Charts'](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/releases) is supporting swift 4.

```
pod 'Charts'
```

Here is list of previous release supporting Swift version below 4.0.

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/releases

Try previous release of cosmos like:

```
pod 'Charts', '~> 3.0.3'
// or
pod 'Charts', '~> 3.0.2'
// or
pod 'Charts', '~> 3.0.1'
```

'

Similar way you can find previous release of Alamofire (supporting Swift below 4.0) from here - [Alamofire - Releases](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/releases)

Try this with `Swift 3.2` and see:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Tranquil' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

# Pods for TranquillocationText
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'UICircularProgressRing', '~> 1.7'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Charts', '3.0.3'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.0.0'

end
```

Comment: Still its the same.

Comment: Thank you.I just tried this and it works! `# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Tranquil' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    
    # Pods for TranquillocationText
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'UICircularProgressRing', '~> 1.7'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'Charts', '3.0.3'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.0.0'
    
end
`

Answer (score 0):

Go to build settings of the target 'Tranquil' then to the section 'Swift Language Version' and set it to 'Swift 4.0'. Next, reinstall your pods with a command 'pod install'. Next, rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks.But I want to remain in 'Swift 3.2'