# Module not found - cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to pod install this [library](https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift) into my project's (lets say child xcodeproj) parent project (lets say Parent xcodeproj).

Child .xcodeproj has its own podfile where I have added RxSwift, RxCocoa, Realm and this GeoSwift library. Here is the cocoapods file as show below

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, "9.0"
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

project 'LocationManager/LocationManager'

def pods 

    pod 'GEOSwift'
    pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.0'
end

target 'LocationManager' do

    pods

    target 'LocationManagerTests' do

        inherit! :search_paths

        pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 4.0'
        pod 'RxTest', '~> 4.0'
    end
end
```

This LocationManager is installed into another `XCode` project as another podfile

```
def location_pods
   pod 'GEOSwift'


   pod 'LocationManager', :git => 'git@github.com:myrepo/locationmanager.git', :branch => 'users/me/add-geoswift'

end

target 'TestApp' do

   location_pods

   project 'TestApp.project'
end
```

When I try to compile the TestApp target, XCode throws an error as below
[image]
GeoSwift module is not found. This error is inside the `Pods > LocationManager > MockLocationManager.swift` The same module imported else where in that `Pods > LocationManager` works. Also `import RxSwift` and `import RxCoca` works. When I accessed `Pods > Targets > LocationManager > Build Phases > Target Dependencies` I see all the pods except GeoSwift
[image]

May I know how to fix this issue? Adding `GeoSwift` to this targetDependency doesn't compile either. When compiling `LocationManager.xcworkspace` as a separate entity it works perfectly fine. That module `import GeoSwift` doesn't throw any compilation error.

Comment: You're missing a closing single-quote (`'`) at the end of line 5 of your second code block. Could that produce an issue like this?

Comment: did you clean and Build your Workspace after pod install ?

Comment: @MichaelHulet Thanks for the catch. Its just an error while typing. Thats not the issue.

Comment: @Rivendell No that didnt help either

Comment: you have try to update pod ?

Comment: @Rivendell That didn't fix either

Comment: Your `pods` debug, release mode in `Build Settings` and `Projects` debug, release mode in `Build Settings` should be same.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue similar to this.

Go into Pods:

[image: Image of the Pods button]

Then click on "Build Settings", find the row titled "Swift Language Version", and try updating it to the latest (in my case, it was 4.1).

[image: How to update your Swift version]

This worked for me! Hopefully it helps someone else out there too.

More info: [Xcode 9 Swift Language Version (SWIFT_VERSION)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338588/xcode-9-swift-language-version-swift-version)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know Cocoapods do not support sub-projects. I had an issue with this too and I promoted all my sub-projects as folders within the main project and put them under a different target. Now those targets can use Cocoapods too.