# Value for SWIFT_VERSION cannot be empty

Tags: swift, xcode10

I have installed swift pods for the obj c project. I got this error when I was trying to build it.

[image]

I have gone through all the solutions like deleting derived data, cleaning the build folder. Swift Compiler_Language also missing in the XCode 10.
Added user-defined setting too, even it didn't work.

Comment: In case you got here after adding a Core Data model to an Objective-C project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763481/74118

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Select your app target then goto build setting, search for `swift` set the swift language version from the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: There is no option of SWIFT COMPILER -LANGUAGE in Xcode 10. That is the issue. Is there any solution to fix?

Comment: i thought you we're right and xcode 10 removed the `Swift Language Version` option, this only available to older version. So i created a new iOS Project but found the `Swift Language Version` in that project. Make sure you select the correct target and goto the `Build settings` tab and search for `swift lan` it will show up.

Comment: It didn't work. I have created a new project and followed the rest of the procedure. Still, no options...:(

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot what you get in `Build Setting` while opening a new project and searched for `swift lan`. Please share the exact xcode 10 version.

Comment: Please check the attached screenshot.

Comment: Select the mother project's target, not the `Pods` target. By mother project i mean the project which included this pods as dependency

Comment: Yes. Working. Thank you so much.:)

Comment: Strange, in a Flutter iOS project, the swift version is available in Pods target build settings for Xcode 10.

Answer (score 36):

In case there is anybody else reading through this thread who has this same problem but was unable to solve it using the above answers, this may help:

If you have a data model, you need to check that when you click on the data model, click on an entity, and bring up the file inspector, the "Code Generation" Language is properly set. In my case my whole app was written Objective-C, but was set here to Swift for some reason. This is another reason that Error will show up in the Issue Navigator.

**It's very important** to clear the build folder after changing Code Generation Language. This can be done by pressing **<kbd>Command-Shift-K</kbd>** or by ***clicking Product->Clean Build Folder*** in the menu at the top of the screen.

Check out this link for a picture of where to find the **"Code Generation"** option I'm talking about.

[Model.xcdatamodeld->File Inspector->Code Generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbgA0.png)

Comment: Thank you, @bmpatterson this was the answer for me :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks: This happened to me after adding a new model to Objective-C project, before even generating the code for entity objects.  Lost hours.  Glad I read down this far.

Comment: tyvm! This was the reason that I was having the build error!

Comment: This is a proof Swift ruined Apple development joy and coherency. Swift introduction created tons of Xcode new problems, incoherencies, needed tweaks. Thanks for this one I would never have found this myself!

Comment: Glad to see it's helped a few people!

Answer (score 11):

Update for Xcode 10.2

1. Go to --> **Build Setting**
2. Select **All + Combined** or **All + Levels** underneath the Build Settings
3. And Finally on the **search bar**, on the right hand side search for "**Swift Language Version**"

[image: as you see in the image worked for me]

Answer (score 4):

For a Cordova app add the following line in config.xml

```
<preference name="SwiftVersion" value="5.3"/>
```

Comment: <preference name="SwiftVersion" value="5.3"/>

Answer (score 3):

You need to  search for every "PRODUCT_NAME ="
There needs to be a " SWIFT_VERSION = "4.2"; " after everyone.
eg. also `PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";enter code here`

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer with guidelines from the guide.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ionic with Cordova and you got here because of this error do this:

In your config.xml add

```
<platform name="ios">
        <preference name="UseSwiftLanguageVersion" value="5" />
```

You may need to remove the resource for ios and re-add it to make it work.

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Still, after all of that, if you're still at lost, you can add a SWIFT_VERSION directly the project file:

```
        80B11AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC3E5D8 /* Debug */ = {
        isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
        baseConfigurationReference = DF5...040;
        buildSettings = {
            ...
            PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME = react-native-some-module;
            ...
            SWIFT_VERSION = "4.2";
        };
        name = Debug;
    };
```

Repeat for both the Debug and Release targets. That had me hop over this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I use circle ci to run tests and generate app previews on testFlight
I was having this issue and was able to fix this issue by setting the SWIFT_VERSION under `ios/{your_project_name}.xcodeproj/project.pcxproj`.

1. Search for `SWIFT_VERSION` under this file and COPY IT

```
    13B07F941A680F5B00A75B9A /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            baseConfigurationReference = 8F6A6E403A1DCB019B5AB844 /* Pods-heartland_charter_s_34954.debug.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                ...
                PRODUCT_NAME = heartland_charter_s_34954;
                SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-Onone";
                SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0; // Copy this line
                ...
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
```

2. Search for `PRODUCT_NAME` and paste the `SWIFT_VERSION` just under each `PRODUCT_NAME` block, provided that it is not already there

```
        13B07F951A680F5B00A75B9A /* Release */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            baseConfigurationReference = CF85766339BED655A366B986 /* Pods-heartland_charter_s_34954.release.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                ...
                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                SWIFT_VERSION = 5.0; // Add it here
                ...
            };
            name = Release;
        };
```

3. pod install and re run the app

Answer (score 0):

if you search for swift_version in "Build Settings" of your target, you will find right away :)